# Use useEffect or not

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Is it bad practice to use useEffect?
And should useEffect be avoided if possible due to re-renders?

This question arised yesterday when a colleague asked for a code review and we had different opinions on how to solve this.

We are creating an app that shows some kind of documentation which could be sorted in chronological or reversed chronological order. This is decided by a button in the apps top bar with a default value of chronological order, this value is stored in a global redux state and will be used in every call to fetch documentation.

In this example we update sortOrder on button click and as an effect of that we fetch data.
If I understand this correctly, we render once when sortOrder state change, and once after data is fetched.

*Pseudo code ish*

```
interface AppState = {
    sortOrder: SortOrder:
    documentation: Documentation[];
}

reducer(){
    case toggleSortOrder:
        const order = state.sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        return {
            ....state,
            sortOrder: order;
        }
}

const AppBar = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return <div><button onClick={dispatch(toggleSortOrder)}>Change sort order</button> 
       </div>;
}

const DocumentationList = (type: DocumentationType) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const sortOrder = useSelector((state) => state.appState.sortOrder);
    const documentation = useSelector((state) => state.appState.documentation);

    useEffect(() => {
        // action is caught by redux-saga and a call to docApi is made through axios
        dispatch(getDocumentation.request(type, sortOrder)
    },[sortOrder]);

    return documentation.map((doc) => <Documentation data={doc} />);
}
```

Is this bad practice?
Should we avoid useEffect and fetch data on click and update sortOrder in saga instead?

Reading docs and blogs I mostly see examples of how en when to use them.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would go with solution more-less like yours, with splitting responsibilities between element which externally changes query params, and element which is displaying data based on current query params. If you decide to put all logic in button click handler then you are kinda coupling too much list and button, because in order to delegate all work to button click you must dig into DocumentationList fetch-data implementation and to copy it to another place(button related saga or in button click handler) in order to fetch data from another place in the app, and not just from the DocumentationList itslef.
From my perspective, only DocumentationList should be responsible to fetch data, and noone else. But you should provide way to subscribe, from documentation list, to some external query params(sort, filters etc) and when they change(if they exist) data should be loaded.

Right now you only have sort, but in case when you can potentially have more params that can be externally modified, then I would dedicate more complex redux part to query params, something like `documentationQueryParams: { sort: "asc", filters: { name: "doc a", type: "type b" } }`, and then inside `DocumentationList` I would use custom hook, for example `const queryParms = useDocumentationQueryParams();` which will return standardized query params, and in useEffect I would subscribe to those queryParms change - whenever they change I will easily fetch new data since you know what is the structure of the queryParms(they must be standardized is some way). Like this you coupled them but in very flexible way, whenever you need new param you will update only filter/query-related component, because in DocumentationList you relay on standardized hook output and you can easily create generic mechanism to output query string, or body data, in order to make new request and to fetch new data.

In terms of performance, there is really no difference between hooks-based approach and moving all to click handlers, because in DocumentationList your render part should rerender only when list change, no matter how list is being changed.

Comment: Thank you! But regarding the render; won't an update to sortOrder cause a render in documentationList since I use useSelector on that?

Comment: It will cause, but  you can easily move `documentation.map((doc) => <Documentation data={doc} />)` to useMemo and to memoize it, since it is obvious that this part should rerender only when `documentation` changes - you will end up with `const list = useMemo(() => .... , [documentation] )` and like this list will recompute/rerender only when documentation changes. Also you can move this part in separate component, and like that you will easily isolate and memoize to avoid unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: Thank you, that's a really good point!